# QDropEvent::pos () always returns 0,0

Tags: qt, pyqt

I reimplemented dropEvent(self, ev) on QGraphicsScene and the whole drag and drop functionality looks working fine except that ev.pos() always returns 0,0 and I am not able to position properly the item on the scene when dropped. What could be the issue?

Comment: You might be getting the coordinates in item coordinate. Try using the scene coordinates and check the result ..

Comment: You are right. I was looking for scene coordinates method, but somehow I was blind and didn't manage to find it.

Comment: added it as the answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of ev.pos() use ev.scenePos() to get the position in scene co-ordinate system, which will return you proper co-ordinate values.